# Grails: Error in getting jar in maven local repo

Tags: java, maven, grails, grails-plugin

I added `compile 'org.grails.plugins:logback:0.3.1'` in `BuildConfig.groovy` dependencies. The plugin that I added is already present in my local repository but when I try to run my app, I got:

`Resolve error obtaining dependencies: Failed to read artifact descriptor for ch.qos.logback:logback-core:jar:1.0.12`

Here's my repositories declaration:

```
repositories {
    inherits true // Whether to inherit repository definitions from plugins

    // grailsPlugins()
    // grailsHome()
    mavenLocal()
    // grailsCentral()
    // mavenCentral()
    // uncomment these (or add new ones) to enable remote dependency resolution from public Maven repositories
    // mavenRepo "http://repository.codehaus.org"
    // mavenRepo "http://download.java.net/maven/2/"
    // mavenRepo "http://repository.jboss.com/maven2/"
}
```

Dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    // specify dependencies here under either 'build', 'compile', 'runtime', 'test' or 'provided' scopes e.g.
    // runtime 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.

    compile 'org.grails.plugins:logback:0.3.1'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i think there is a version mismatch with the jars that you have in your local .m2 and what you are downloading. Can you delete the local .m2 directory and try to install your project once again

Comment: `ch.qos.logback:logback-core:jar:1.0.12` is also present in my local repo. I cant delete the whole .m2 so I just deleted all logback but same error.